# Configuring OAuth 2 Authentication with NativeScript provided Enterprise Auth project template

Tags: nativescript, kinvey

I am Configuring OAuth 2 Authentication with NativeScript provided Enterprise Auth project template, I followed the complete guide to configure Azure Active Directory. After setting up URLs and keys when I am executing the application through tns preview, it is giving me following error:

https://auth.kinvey.com/v3/oauth/auth?client_id=kid_SJcDEau7N&redirect_uri=nsplayresume%3A%2F%2F&response_type=code&scope=openid

Error:
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client authentication failed.","debug":"Client Verification Failed: redirect uri not valid"}

When I check the login script it was showing error because there was no argument given in the Kinvey.User.loginWithMIC() function so I provided Kinvey.User.loginWithMIC('http://example.com') as it was showing in the video tutorial.

```
login() {
    if (Kinvey.User.getActiveUser() == null) {
        Kinvey.User.loginWithMIC()
            .then((user: Kinvey.User) => {
                this.navigateHome();
                console.log("user: " + JSON.stringify(user));
            })
            .catch((error: Kinvey.BaseError) => {
                alert("An error occurred. Check your Kinvey settings.");
                console.log("error: " + error);
            });
    } else {
        this.navigateHome();
    }
}
```

as expected it should show the login screen for the account which I have configured in Azure Active Directory.

Comment: If I use a valid `redirect_uri` URL like `http://example.com`, it seems to work. Do you have a Playground sample where your issue can be reproduced?

Comment: I am using redirect uri in Kinvey Console also using that url in login code as shown below: 
Kinvey.User.loginWithMIC('http://example.com')
                .then((user: Kinvey.User) => {
                    this.navigateHome();
                    console.log("user: " + JSON.stringify(user));
                })

Comment: Hi Manoj,

I am using this plugin from NativeScript site [link](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/tns-template-enterprise-auth-ng)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/bilger-progress/NativeScriptKinveyMIC) I have a *NativeScript solution*, which makes use of *Kinvey's Mobile Identity Connect*. It's basically built using the same template that you would like to make use of. There are couple of important steps, that you need to take care before running that project, they are as follows:

- Open `kinvey.common.ts` file from inside the `src/app/shared` folder and
  set your *Application ID* and *Application Secret* (and *Instance ID* if
  present, if not - remove the attribute). That's needed so that the *NativeScript application* can connect to your *Kinvey Backend*.
- Open the *Login component's TypeScript controller* and set your *MIC identifier*. The *MIC identifier* is the *MIC Service's ID*. That will tell the app which service to refer to from the backend.
- Open the *MIC Service settings* from the *Kinvey Console* and set `myscheme://` as a *redirect URI*. The *authorization endpoint* normally redirects the user back to the client’s registered *redirect URL*. Depending on the platform, native apps can either claim a *URL pattern*, or register a *custom URL scheme* that will launch the application. For example, an *iOS application* may register a custom protocol such as `myapp://` and then use a `redirect_uri` of `myapp://callback`.

For most up-to-date list of those crucial items, you can check out the repository's *README* file. Try that, and let me know if you can get *Kinvey MIC* working.

Comment: I followed the same steps as you have mentioned above, but I was trying to run my application on NativeScript Preview app on iOS where I was getting the error. When I installed the android emulator and tried to run on it then it was working fine. Thank you for guiding me, Bilger!

Comment: Sure, no worries!